# Java - indexing into array with a byte

Tags: java, arrays, byte

Is it possible to index a Java array based on a byte?

i.e. something like

```
array[byte b] = x;
```

I have a very performance-critical application which reads b (in the code above) from a file, and I don't want the overhead of converting this to an int. What is the best way to achieve this? Is there a performance-decrease as a result of using this method of indexing rather than an int?

With many thanks,

Froskoy.

Comment: I can't speak to the performance issue. If you want this I'd use a ByteBuffer and iterate through it. ByteBuffer is pretty optimized... You could also use a direct ByteBuffer

Comment: Have you tried it? Hint - it compiles...

Comment: If you're reading from a file on a physical disk (even an SSD), then conversions from `byte` to `int` are going to be utterly insignificant compared with the path it takes to get the data out in the first place.

Comment: I wouldn't assume there is a significant performance hit until you have measured it and it causing a problem for you program. Worry about performance when its isn't a problem leads to poor design choices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no overhead for "converting this to an int."  At the Java bytecode level, all `byte`s are already `int`s.

In any event, doing array indexing will automatically upcast to an `int` anyway.  None of these things will improve performance, and many will decrease performance.  Just leave your code using an `int`.

[The JVM specification, section 2.11.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1):

> Note that most instructions in Table 2.2 do not have forms for the integral types byte, char, and short. None have forms for the boolean type. Compilers encode loads of literal values of types byte and short using Java virtual machine instructions that sign-extend those values to values of type int at compile-time or runtime. Loads of literal values of types boolean and char are encoded using instructions that zero-extend the literal to a value of type int at compile-time or runtime. Likewise, loads from arrays of values of type boolean, byte, short, and char are encoded using Java virtual machine instructions that sign-extend or zero-extend the values to values of type int. Thus, most operations on values of actual types boolean, byte, char, and short are correctly performed by instructions operating on values of computational type int.

Comment: "all bytes are already ints" Won't it have to do sign extension to fill the extra bits on the upcast? Or is there some other mechanism that I'm not aware of?

Comment: The sign extension is _already there._  As soon as you have a method-local variable that's a `byte`, it's actually implemented as an `int`.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Do you happen to know a JLS citation for that? J/w, it's fine if you don't, I can investigate it myself tonight.

Comment: I updated my answer with an actual demonstration from real code.

Comment: As far as I understood his question, he meant accessing _any_ type of array with a `byte` variable, such as `Object[] objs; byte b;` ... `Object obj = objs[b];` However, from your example, it seems that it doesn't matter, it'll result in the same behavior anyway. Thanks +1

Answer (score 3):

As all integer types in java are signed you have anyway to mask out 8 bits of b's value provided you do expect to read from the file values greater than 0x7F:

```
byte b;
byte a[256];
a [b & 0xFF] = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

No; [array indices are non-negative integers (JLS 10.4)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4-120), but byte indices will be promoted.

Comment: But "Arrays must be indexed by int values; short, byte, or char values may also be used as index values because they are subjected to unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) and become int values. "

Comment: @Zoe So it's indexed by an int--but I could have been clearer.

Comment: I think you had it.  just a bit terse to understand.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no performance decrease, because on the moment you read the byte, you store it in a [CPU register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) sometime. Those registers always works with [WORDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28data_type%29), which means that the byte is always "converted" to an int (or a long, if you are on a 64 bit machine).

So, simply read your byte like this:

```
int b = (in.readByte() & 0xFF);
```

If your application is that performance critical, you should be optimizing elsewhere.