# Is it safe to use a short as the index for an array?

Tags: java, arrays, short

In java or swift is it safe to use a short in the index of an array, ex.

```
short r = 2;
System.out.println(myArray[r]);
```

Usually we use int for this, but the idea of using a short never crossed my path until now.

Comment: Just keep your short below 32,767 and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it safe? Yes. I wouldn't recommend it though. People copy/paste code all the time. You might copy `short` usage in a loop.

Arrays in java have max size of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so if you were to write

`for(short s = 0; s < array.length; s++) { // ... }`

You would end up getting a overflow because the length of the array can be larger than a short.

Comment: Good call on the `s++` overflow

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is no problem to use `short` as array index. You may also use `byte` [as array index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630482/java-indexing-into-array-with-a-byte). But you have only to remember that the array index can not be negative.

In java `short` are 16 bits or 2 bytes. So it is long enough to be used as an index of an array in normal situation.